# Regsvr32 /u - Unregister DLL

Tags: registry, registrykey

`Regsvr32 /u` can unregister the DLL but can't remove its corresponding entries in the registry.

Is there a script or tool that can i use to remove all these registry values? I cant remove it one by one there are too many entries.

It is more convenient if someone can provide a sample .bat file.

UPDATE : 
I create a script but i cant echo result inside loop :)

```
@echo off
for /f  %%a in (' 
    reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" ^|
    find "Search_Text"
') do (
     set "regs=%%a"
     echo %regs%
)

pause
::echo %regs%
::reg delete "%regs%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [delayed expansion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) (also see [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491001.aspx)).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (' 
    reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" ^|
    find "Search_Text"
') do (
    set "regs=%%a"
    echo !regs!
    echo reg delete "!regs!"
)
```

Side note: You don't need delayed expansion if you don't work with variables in the loop body:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in (' 
    reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" ^|
    find "Search_Text"
') do (
    echo %%a
    echo reg delete "%%a"
)
```